# Divergence theorem in 3D

Tags: integration, 3d, volume, divergence-theorem

I'm having a very hard time with the following problem:

Consider an area $D$ given by:
\begin{cases}
\frac{x^2}{4} + y^2 \leq 1\\
0 \leq z \leq -x
\end{cases}

Let $\vec{F} = (y+e^y)\vec{j} + z(1-e^y)\vec{k}$. Check the Divergence Theorem for $\vec{F}$ on $D$  by calculating both sides of the theorem:

\begin{equation}
\iiint_{D}div\vec{F}dV = \oint\oint_{S} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{N}dS \quad \text{(\oiint doesn't seem to exist here)}
\end{equation}

For the divergence I've got
\begin{equation}
div\vec{F} = 0 + (1+e^y) + (1-e^y) = 2
\end{equation}
So I'd get
\begin{equation}
\iiint_{D} 2dxdydz
\end{equation}

But from this point on I can't seem to figure out what to do. I've tried using the integration limits
\begin{cases}
-2 \leq x \leq 0 \\
-1 \leq y \leq 1 \\
0 \leq z \leq -x
\end{cases}
(I understand now after writing that these integration limits would only work when $D$ was rectangular instead of having a ellipse shape)

I chose these according to this sketch I made of $D$, which seemed right considering that $\frac{x^2}{4} + y^2 \leq 1$ should give $D$ an ellipse shaped base:

[image: sketch D]

But when integrating over these limits I got
\begin{equation}
\iiint_{D} 2dxdydz = 0
\end{equation}

After this I tried a parametrization for ellipses, which I've never used or seen before and am not very confident in being right. I got:
\begin{cases}
x = 2u\cos(v)\\
y = u\sin(v)\\
z = w
\end{cases}
With the Jacobian of this transformation being $J = 2u$
Now for the limits for these new variables I chose
\begin{cases}
0 \leq u \leq 1\\
0 \leq v \leq \pi \\
0 \leq w \leq 2u\cos(v)
\end{cases}

When integrating this I get

\begin{equation}
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\pi}\int_{0}^{2cos(v)}(2 \cdot 2u) dudvdw\\
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{\pi}4u \cdot 2u\cos(v) dudv
\end{equation}
But integrating this from $0$ to $\pi$ would again result in $0$.

I can't figure out what I should do and my lecture notes and example problems don't seem to help me further. Can someone give me a hint on how to continue?

Comment: "I've tried using the integration limits..." . They are wrong: inded $\;-2\le x\le0\;$, yet $\;-\sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}4}\le y\le \sqrt{1-\frac{x^2}4}\;$

Comment: $$\int _0^2\int _{-2}^{-z}\int _{-\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4-x^2}}^{+\frac{1}{2} \sqrt{4-x^2}}2\cdot dydxdz=\frac{16}{3}$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limits of integration for $D$ are wrong. The LHS should be
$$\begin{align}\iiint_{D} 2dxdydz &=\int_{y=-1}^{1}(\int_{x=-2\sqrt{1-y^2}}^0(\int_{z=0}^{-x}2dz)dx)dy
\\&=-\int_{y=-1}^{1}(\int_{x=-2\sqrt{1-y^2}}^02xdx)dy\\
&=4\int_{y=-1}^{1}(1-y^2)dy=\frac{16}{3}.
\end{align}$$
The RHS is the sum of the fluxes through the three surfaces given by the boundary of $D$:
$$\iint_{S_1} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{N}dS+
\iint_{S_2} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{N}dS+\iint_{S_3} \vec{F} \cdot \vec{N}dS$$
where
$$S_1=\{(x,y,0):y\in[-1,1], -2\sqrt{1-y^2}\leq  x \leq 0\},$$
$$S_2=\{(x,y,-x):y\in[-1,1], -2\sqrt{1-y^2}\leq  x \leq 0\},$$
$$S_3=\{(2\cos(t),\sin(t),z):t\in[\pi/2,3\pi/2], 0\leq z\leq -2\cos(t)\}.$$
The orientation is outward. Try to evaluate the three fluxes and verify the equality.